# THREE JS creating a custom shape geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, shapes

I've been trying to build and visualize an excisting city using THREE.js 3-dimensional. For this I have coordinates for about 1000 buildings. Since each building can have any n-number of corners it's not possible to use the cubeGeometry so i tried to create a custom geometry without much succes. The buildingCoords specify all the building coordinates for the building relative to the center of the scene, it also includes both floor height coordinates as well as roof height coordinates for each building. 
The problem is when I render it like this, it's not taking into account any heights (somehow the extrusion settings are giving it a height, which is not the actual height of a building), in addition the extrude settings gives it very weird shapes overall. 
The biggest problem is that I haven't been able to find any documentation on how extrusion works, I've been trying a lot of different values for the extrusion setting variables, but I've been unable to get anything close to the result I'm looking for :(, which is a building with corners on the given coordinates with no weird curves or mutated shapes.

Here's an example for one building:

```
        var buildings = [];
        var buildingCoords = [new THREE.Vector3(-330.8653652173956,-312.7242347826201,0),new THREE.Vector3(-329.8339913043564,-310.8272434783638,0),new THREE.Vector3(-324.56661739130294,-313.6665913044507,0),new THREE.Vector3(-325.6655217391161,-315.69250434781463,0),new THREE.Vector3(-330.8653652173956,-312.7242347826201,0),new THREE.Vector3(-330.8653652173956,-312.7242347826201,6.75304347826087),new THREE.Vector3(-329.8339913043564,-310.8272434783638,6.75304347826087),new THREE.Vector3(-324.56661739130294,-313.6665913044507,6.75304347826087),new THREE.Vector3(-325.6655217391161,-315.69250434781463,6.75304347826087),new THREE.Vector3(-330.8653652173956,-312.7242347826201,6.75304347826087)];
        buildingShape = new THREE.Shape(buildingCoords);
        var extrusionSettings = {amount: 10, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 3, steps: 4, bevelThickness: 8, material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1};
        var buildingGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(buildingShape, extrusionSettings);
        var buildingMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xcccccc});  
        var building = new THREE.Mesh(buildingGeometry,buildingMaterial );
        buildings.push(building);
        scene.add(building);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you use both upper and lower plane of the building in buildingCoords.

Use amount parameter in extrusion settings to set height of the building.

You should use just the lower plane  (first half, where Z coordinate is 0)

http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry.js.html

Comment: Than how should I include the height for a building?

Comment: Try size parameter instead of height.

Comment: It's still showing the same height for every building if I use the height variable in extrude geometry. =/
It's looking slightly better though but building heights have to be accurate.

I am now using (as an example):
var extrusionSettings = {height: 9.208695652173914, bevelEnabled: false};

Maybe I'm forgetting something?

Here's an example of how it looks in the browser:
http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa110/teugata/badExample_zps90dfa224.png

Comment: Size is not working either unfortunately, still looks the same.

Comment: I went on a hunch and used "amount:" . That seemed to work. Thnx for your help!